# Why is Karaf maven plugin unable to find feature while creating assembly?

Tags: karaf

Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.7:assembly (default-assembly) on project myproject-assembled: Unable to build assembly: Could not find matching feature

Where do I start to look ?

Comment: Could you share the relevant parts of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My original issue was resolved. I had just not specified the feature.xml correctly.